# Why the limit of a quotient is not the quotient of a limit?

Tags: limits

In various questions regarding why $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can't be treated as a ratio, the main arguement used in most of the answer is: "And because we cannot express this limit-of-a-quotient as a-quotient-of-the-limits".

Why the limit of a quotient is not the quotient of a limit ?

Comment: A better question: Why *would* it be? Alternatively, write down a bunch of limits of quotients and see they aren't quotients of the corresponding limits.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I am asking why it is (for the intuive feel for it).

Comment: I always find it strange when people ask for an intuitive reason for why something is false. I think a vastly better place to start is addressing any (necessarily incorrect) intuition that the statement is true.

Comment: The limit of a quotient *is* the quotient of the limits, if the downstairs limit is nonzero. And if the limit of the denominator is indeed zero, the quotient of the limits is not defined.

Comment: As per @lubin, see limit rules at:http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx and with regards to $dy/dx$ ratio, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio

Answer (score 1):

The limits of the numerator and denominator might not both exist, or both exist but the quotient of the limits might be undefined.

Examples:

- $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac n {n+1}$
- $\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac {(x+h)-x} h$: both limits exist, but $0/0$ is undefined.